# Convert Select with Join to Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a query:

```
SELECT t.*, tb.UpdateDate
FROM #tempBuildings tb INNER JOIN Buildings b ON b.BuildingID = tb.BuildingID 
INNER JOIN @tmp t ON t.ID = b.InvestmentId
```

I know it's hard to understand what is here, but in few words:
I have table with buildings, and in #tempBuildings I'm counting date of update.

It's not my idea , but I must add to output one column.

So in temp table @tmp I've added this column , and I must this select query convert to update query
foreach row I must do something like:

```
update @tmp set @tmp.UpdateDate=tb.UpdateDate
```

I'm sorry for luck of clarity but construction of this queries is incredible.

I'm using sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE t set t.UpdateDate=tb.UpdateDate
FROM #tempBuildings tb 
INNER JOIN Buildings b ON b.BuildingID = tb.BuildingID 
INNER JOIN @tmp t ON t.ID = b.InvestmentId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update t
set t.UpdateDate = tb.UpdateDate
FROM #tempBuildings tb 
INNER JOIN Buildings b ON b.BuildingID = tb.BuildingID 
INNER JOIN @tmp t ON t.ID = b.InvestmentId
```